# Не срабатывает событие, при в взаимодействии с iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, playerjs

Если сначала нажимаю на плеер, а затем нажимаю на кнопку два раза, то срабатывает.  Если сразу нажимаю на кнопку, то событие не срабатывает, запускается проигрывание плеера, но смена языка не происходит даже после пяти нажатий. Команды отправляются по API, но с таким условием, если нажимаю сначала на плеер.  Есть ли идеи как можно это решить?

```html
    <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315" src="https://cdn.plrjs.com/player/a6shyesb5htna/3tyyw8wec3yk.html?file=https://cdne2-vod-hls.cdnvideo.ru/cdne2-vod/_definst_/mp4:cdne2/promo_2020/multi_lang/ped20_rus-l_eng-r_with_title_01.mp4/playlist.m3u8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <button class="buttonCl" onclick="rus1()">RUS</button>
    <button class="buttonCl" onclick="eng0()">ENG</button>
    <script>
    function rus1(event, id, info) {
        document.getElementById("player").contentWindow.postMessage({ "api": "channel", "set": 1 }, "*");
        document.getElementById("player").contentWindow.postMessage({ "api": "volume", "set": 0.3 }, "*");
        document.getElementById("player").contentWindow.postMessage({ "api": "play" }, "*");
    }

    function eng0(event, id, info) {
        document.getElementById("player").contentWindow.postMessage({ "api": "channel", "set": 0 }, "*");
        document.getElementById("player").contentWindow.postMessage({ "api": "volume", "set": 0.5 }, "*");
        document.getElementById("player").contentWindow.postMessage({ "api": "play" }, "*");
    }
    </script>
```